# If I charge Nexus 4 with a wireless charger will it charge considering red LED error

Tags: charging, nexus-4

I've had a red LED error in my Nexus 4 for a week and it won't turn on or charge. I've tried everything, pressing the power button for 60 seconds, etc. I even opened it up and removed the battery and plugged it back in. It just won't help. I think it's due to very low power levels in the phone and it won't even charge. I was thinking that if I charge with a wireless charger will it charge or not?

Also if I charge it with an iPad charger the LED becomes stable red otherwise it's blinking using LG's original charger. So what's the issue and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 1):

If you have the red LED and the device won't charge from the wall, using the original charger, then it's faulty. Send it back for a replacement.

Comment: I live In pakistan , and I can't get it replaced from here. Any other solution?

Comment: Isn't there any LG service center? Go to one of them and try.